# Import Schemas in Azure Data Factory with Parameters

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I am trying to develop a simple ADF pipeline that copies data from a delimited file to MySQL database, when such a file is uploaded to a Blob Storage Account. I am using parameters to define the name of the Storage Account, the Container that houses the files and file name (inputStorageAccount, inputContainer, inputFile). The name of the Storage Account is a global parameter and the other two are meant to be provided by the trigger. The Linked Service has also been parameterized.
However, I want to define the mappings for this operation. So, I am trying to 'import schemas' by providing the values for these parameters (I have stored a sample file in the Storage Account). But, I keep getting this error when trying to do so,

[image: Error code 24101]

What am I doing wrong? How can I get this to work?

I would also like to know why I am not being asked to provide a value for the inputContainer parameter when I try to use 'import schema' at the dataset level,
[image: Import schema from dataset]

Answer (score 0):

Where you have to add the values `Add dynamic content` [Alt+P] :

[image]

Just as mentioned here in the below Snip, Go to the `+` Symbol where you will find a window and need to fill in the parameter name, type and value:

[image]

Where we can directly select the parameter according to the options :

[image]

Here is another detailed scenario which might help: Using Azure DataFactory Parameterized Linked Service | [Docs](https://mrpaulandrew.com/2018/11/15/using-data-factory-parameterised-linked-services/), then you can reset the schema.